# Disable scrolling on visual viewport size changes (e.g. when zooming)

Tags: javascript, scroll

When zooming in, the visual viewport size changes, and the scrollbars appear. Is there a way to disable scrolling in that situation?

Note that I mean zooming by touchpad (pinch zooming), not by ctrl + mouse wheel.

[gif demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Nca.gif)

I just want to disable scrolling for the visual viewport, not other possible scrollable elements.
(I've already found a way to disable scrolling for all scrollable elements here: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily))

And note that overflow:hidden obviously doesn't relate to this problem.

something like this would be ideal, but the problem is that the event isn't `defaultPrevented` anyway!:

```
visualViewport.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Apparently this is sadly not possible. The visualViewport scroll events are not `cancelable`.